# clang error "explicit instantiation does not refer to a function template" across multiple namespaces

Tags: c++, templates, gcc, namespaces, clang

I'm trying to **reuse existing templated functions from a namespace in my own namespace** and explicitly instantiate them for code coverage reasons.

The following code compiles with gcc 9.3 but does **not** compile with clang 10.0.0

```
namespace bar {
    template<typename T>
    T func(T arg){ return arg;};
}

namespace foo {
    using bar::func;
}

template int foo::func<int>(int);

int main()
{ }
```

View example [here](https://godbolt.org/z/affeWq)

If i instantiate the template function as

```
template int bar::func<int>(int);
```

clang compiles as well. But this is not what i want.

**Is it possible to explicitly instantiate a template function across namespaces with clang?**

**Why do gcc and clang give different results?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do that, I'm afraid. Clang is correct.

> **[temp.explicit]**
>
> [2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/temp.explicit#2) The syntax for explicit instantiation is:
>
> ```
> explicit-instantiation:  
>     externopt template declaration
> ```
>
> [4](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/temp.explicit#4.sentence-1) If the explicit instantiation is for a class or member class,
> the elaborated-type-specifier in the declaration shall include a
> simple-template-id; otherwise, the declaration shall be a
> simple-declaration whose init-declarator-list comprises a single
> init-declarator that does not have an initializer.

This paragraph tells us that the bit after the `template` keyword must be both syntactically and semantically a valid declaration for something (and must not contain an initializer, which isn't relevant here). A declaration has several parts, but the one of interest here is the *declarator* part of the declaration.

About that we have the following paragraph

> **[dcl.meaning]** (emphasis mine)
>
> [1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/dcl.meaning#1) A declarator contains exactly one declarator-id; it names the
> identifier that is declared. An unqualified-id occurring in a
> declarator-id shall be a simple identifier except for the declaration
> of some special functions ([class.ctor], [class.conv], [class.dtor],
> [over.oper]) and for the declaration of template specializations or
> partial specializations ([temp.spec]). **When the declarator-id is
> qualified**, the declaration shall refer to a previously declared member
> of the class or namespace to which the qualifier refers (or, in the
> case of a namespace, of an element of the inline namespace set of that
> namespace ([namespace.def])) or to a specialization thereof; **the
> member shall not merely have been introduced by a using-declaration in
> the scope of the class or namespace nominated by the
> nested-name-specifier of the declarator-id**.

Since your declarator-id in the explicit template instantiation is `foo::func`, it does not follow the rule laid out in the sentence I marked in bold. That makes your attempt at explicit instantiation ill-formed.

GCC should have rejected your attempt too.